# Android Spinner issue

Tags: android

I have set a value in spinner , from activity-1.
now i am traversing to activity-2 and again coming back to activity-1, i am not getting the updated spinner value which i have selected previously  but i am getting default value(value at index 1) of spinner  .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `Activity` that becomes inactive (invisible to a user) can be destroyed by the system in case of lacking resources. To keep values between `Activity` runs you need to save your state using Bundles. If you look closely to `Activity::onCreate` method you can see it has a parameter:

```
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

So, eg in method `onPause()` you save your desired values and when `Activity` is recreated - load them.

Android documentation contains a chapter how to [save states between `Activity` runs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#SavingPersistentState).